# How to add new languages to system image

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo, android-source

To the currently supported set of languages that we get from Froyo, I would like to add other languages such as Hebrew or Arabic. Is there any way I can update the Froyo code to support these languages and see them in the `settings --> languages & keyboards -->select locale` section after building the Froyo code and installing it on the device.

I have tried adding locales "iw_IL" to the set present in `build/target/product/langugaes_fill.mk` but now luck.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hi In additioin you have to do following changes in file
frameworks/base/core/java/com/android/internal/app/LocalePicker

```
 final String[] localesOld = Resources.getSystem().getAssets().getLocales();
        final String[] locales = new String[localesOld.length+1];
        for(int i=0;i<locales.length;i++){
            if(i<localesOld.length){
                locales[i] = localesOld[i];
            }else{
                locales[i] = "your locale code";
                Log.d(TAG, "%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% locale added %%%%%%%%%%%");
            }
        }
```

I used this add my custom locale and it worked fine.I hope this will solve your issue.